# In an interactive shell why would anyone set IFS to something other than the default?

Tags: bash, shell

Sometimes when writing script it can be necessary to set `IFS`(the internal field separator) to something other than the default, e.g. to change the way `$*` will be expanded.

While this is totally plausible I can't think of any reason to set `IFS` in interactive shells to anything but the default (which is space, tab and newline if I remember correctly). Still I was often told that on an interactive shell I can't expect `IFS` to be set to it's default value.

Is this really true? Can anyone give practical examples?

Comment: Your question would be better if you explained the acronym IFS.

Comment: it is the `internal field separator` in this context.  i agree he should have clarified.

Comment: @foampile Please include it in your question by editing it rather than putting it in a comment. Will be easier for others to spot then.

Comment: @N.N. -- the question was not mine.  do check

Comment: but i did edit the OP, it is pending approval

Comment: why was my edit rejected ?  are you trying to be purposely mysterious?

Comment: @foampile I didn't reject anything :/. But I added the missing information. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an interactive shell, `$IFS` will be the default unless you changed it or something in shell startup scripts (like `~/.bashrc` for `bash`) or any other scripts sourced or shell functions executed since the shell was started change it (they generally wouldn't or would change it back to the default if they are properly written though).

If those functions defined in *rc* files or other *sourced* files are properly written and they need to use word splitting, they would not assume anything on the current value of IFS, so it should be fine for you do set it to a different value.

However, once you change it, you have to remember that you did as that might affect the way command lines you run later are interpreted.

For instance, if you do:

```
IFS=:; ls -- $PATH
```

To list the directories in `$PATH`, you might wonder why later on things like:

```
rm -f -- $(cat ~/my.file.list)
```

do not work any more. So you might as well write it:

```
(IFS=:; ls -- $PATH)
```

Or:

```
IFS=:; ls -- $PATH; unset IFS
```

(BTW, `unset IFS` restores the word splitting to its default behaviour, but not `$IFS` and it breaks the (not properly written) functions that do things like `oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=xxx; ...; IFS=$oldIFS` to restore `$IFS`).

Comment: You can also set it for a single command `IFS=: ls -- $PATH`, without the subshell.

Comment: @jordanm, No. that inserts `IFS=:` into the environment passed to `ls` (which has no use for it), but doesn't affect how that `$PATH` is split in this command line. You could do `IFS=: command eval 'ls -- $PATH'`, but that's a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Why bother with `command eval` when just `eval` seems like it would do in that case?

Comment: Also, "[shell functions] would change [`IFS`] back to the default if they are properly written" can get really hard to achieve for non-trivial portable logic: it's easy if the whole program fits in one human's head, but if you've got function `foo` calling function `bar`, well then `foo` might want to set `IFS` for something *while* calling `bar`, but then someone comes along and refactors `bar` to call function `qux` which was written elsewhere by someone assuming `IFS` would always be the default, and suddenly things break due to not-local-to-`bar` interactions between `foo` and `qux`. (1/2)

Comment: ..and at the same time, unless you can rely on local variables (which are available on every modern shell I've tried on Linux but certainly weren't in Bourne shell) or are willing and able to write your function bodies as subshells, then function `foo` can't just use a name like `old_IFS` to store `IFS` while calling `bar` with a modified `IFS` - because what if `bar` is already or in the future written to use the same trick, setting `old_IFS` internally and thus clobbering the old value. This can be worked-around but you have to consciously go out of the way to handle it. (2/2)

Comment: @mtraceur, compare `sh -c 'IFS=: eval true; echo "$IFS"'` with `sh -c 'IFS=: command eval true; echo "$IFS"'`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can and should expect that `IFS` is set to default, as without it, all sorts of commands will simply stop working altogether.

You change IFS in a shell (temporarily) for the same reasons you do it in a bash script, when you happen to need it (which rarely ever happens). If you're going to use a specific command only once there is no reason to write it into a shell script. Other than that there is no difference between a shell script, and using the shell directly.

Comment: To remove confusion, IFS is not exported to the environment, and even if it is shells, ignore it upon starting, so setting IFS is the interactive shells will not affect any command started by that shell, unless those commands are built in the shell like `read` or `.` (aka `source`) or the functions you define.